# Best source(s) for security related news?

Tags: professional-education, updates

What is the best place to go for security news? I am looking for everything from news updates to editorials to guides and research. Anywhere considered more reliable or particularly hard-hitting?

Also I am looking for good Twitter feeds!

Comment: darkreading.com

Comment: you can get security related updates from http://news.yahoo.com/security/

Comment: This question is not constructive here, and off-topic as per the faq.

Answer (score 5):

For a site I would recommend the SANS Internet Storm Center at https://isc.sans.edu/.

I find the most useful for news for me is a twitter list of security professionals and researchers such as.

- [@sans_isc](https://twitter.com/sans_isc)
- [@uscert_gov](https://twitter.com/uscert_gov)
- [@schneierblog](https://twitter.com/schneierblog)
- [@gcluley](https://twitter.com/gcluley)
- [@duckblog](https://twitter.com/duckblog)
- [@markrussinovich](https://twitter.com/markrussinovich)
- [@jeremiahg](https://twitter.com/jeremiahg)
- [@briankrebs](https://twitter.com/briankrebs)
- [@mikko](https://twitter.com/mikko)
- [@hdmoore](https://twitter.com/hemoore)
- [@dakami](https://twitter.com/dakami)

You can probably find other lists of security related twitter users that would be worthwhile to follow.

Answer (score 3):

http://security.didici.cc/ is all I use nowadays. Not a source per se - it's a news aggregator, but includes many high quality news sources, as well as podcasts, videos, events, CVEs and Tweets (as well as stackexchange posts - which is where I found your question).

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the site.

Comment: Thank you, that is very good! Can you make links become clickable in twitter page?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the *Security* section from my RSS reader, in the form of the OPML file so you can read it directly into yours. It's oriented to news about latest exploits on the 'user level', i.e. what you can encounter 'out there'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml xmlns:rssowl="http://www.rssowl.org" version="1.1">
  <head>
    <title>RSSOwl Subscriptions</title>
    <dateModified>do, 23 mei 2013 11:58:05 CEST</dateModified>
  </head>
  <body>
    <outline text="My Feeds" rssowl:isSet="true" rssowl:id="7">
      <outline text="Computing" rssowl:isSet="false" rssowl:id="1881">
        <outline text="Security" rssowl:isSet="false" rssowl:id="9363">
          <outline text="Latest Hacker News" xmlUrl="http://www.viruslist.com/en/rss/latesthackernews" rssowl:id="9364" />
          <outline text="F-Secure Antivirus Research Weblog" xmlUrl="http://www.f-secure.com/weblog/weblog.rdf" rssowl:id="9365" />
          <outline text="Websense Security Labs Blog" xmlUrl="http://community.websense.com/blogs/securitylabs/rss.aspx" rssowl:id="9366" />
          <outline text="Kasperky Lab Weblog" xmlUrl="http://www.viruslist.com/en/rss/weblog" rssowl:id="9367" />
          <outline text="Schneier on Security" xmlUrl="http://www.schneier.com/blog/index.xml" rssowl:id="9368" />
          <outline text="Safe and Savvy" xmlUrl="http://safeandsavvy.f-secure.com/feed/" rssowl:id="9369" />
          <outline text="Graham Cluley's blog" xmlUrl="http://feeds.sophos.com/en/rss2_0-sophos-graham-cluley.xml" rssowl:id="9370" />
          <outline text="Krebs on Security" xmlUrl="http://www.krebsonsecurity.com/feed/" rssowl:id="9371" />
          <outline text="InSecurity Complex" xmlUrl="http://news.cnet.com/8300-27080_3-245.xml?tag=rtcol;about" rssowl:id="9372" />
          <outline text="Social Media Security" xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/SocialMediaSecurity" rssowl:id="9373" />
          <outline text="SunbeltBLOG" xmlUrl="http://sunbeltblog.blogspot.com/atom.xml" rssowl:id="9374" />
          <outline text="Steve (GRC) Gibson's BlogSteve (GRC) Gibson's Blog" xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/SteveGibsonsBlog" rssowl:id="9375" />
          <outline text="CounterMeasures -  A Security Blog" xmlUrl="http://countermeasures.trendmicro.eu/feed" rssowl:id="9376" />
          <outline text="The Last Watchdog" xmlUrl="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/LastWatchdog" rssowl:id="9377" />
          <outline text="Social Engineering - Security Through Education" xmlUrl="http://www.social-engineer.org/blog/feed/" rssowl:id="9379" />
        </outline>
      </outline>
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
```

Or edit the individual URLs out...

I can also post the *Security* folder from my browser bookmarks (with all subfolders) but that's huge. It's mostly URLs for guides and tutorials and not news.

Comment: Man, some of those haven't been updated in years.  Thanks for the dump though.

Comment: Yeah, I should clean 'm out...

Answer (score 1):

Alright. So they aren't all strictly hacking:

http://www.scmagazine.com.au/News/

http://thehackernews.com/

http://www.ehackingnews.com/

https://news.ycombinator.com/

I don't use twitter, but occasionally i read [The Jester's](https://twitter.com/th3j35t3r) twitter feed, cause frankly, its pretty bad-ass from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Phrack Magazine, also vxheavens when it returns. http://www.shadowserver.org/wiki/ :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want articles from various sources delivered to your inbox, there is a good medium-traffic mailing list at http://infosecnews.org/.