# Best and most current sites for security breaches

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, research

I'm taking my masters in cyber-security and as a student I come across a lot of garbage when doing research.  What are sites with the latest security breaches?   Thanks for the help in advanced.

My current one so far is www.darkreading.com but I'm sure there is much better out there.

Comment: Take a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/which-site-do-you-use-to-view-details-of-vulnerabilities, and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36361/best-sources-for-security-related-news/36366#36366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that the social groups are the best bet for breaking sec news - such as Twitter, Facebook and Reddit.

Check out the 2600 group on facebook, /r/netsec on reddit and start poking around the security news sources on twitter. Honestly there are a ton of different outlets for infosec available these days.

For the more 'established' news sources I use techworm.net and thehackerspot.com. Forbes has some good articles from time to time as well.